# What does it mean to have a retired CA root certificate?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority

I was looking at various CAs and they always have a paged dedicated to list "retired roots".

For example: https://www.thawte.com/roots/retired.html

Does it mean these certificates should not be trusted now? Or does it mean CA will not renew the root once the certificate expire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the certificates described on the retired roots page today have 1024-bit RSA keys (except for the one which says 1025) and were self-signed with either md5WithRSAEncryption or sha1WithRSAEncryption.

The most likely interpretation is "we are not self-revoking these roots, certificates which chain to them are not inherently untrustworthy, but you need to make an application decision to trust them; however, we will not issue any further certificates which chain to these roots".

Answer (score 0):

Retired indicates the certificates are no longer in use, but not compromised and so not revoked. They may also be retired due to expiration. Each CA also publishes a "CPS" or certification practice statement that describes the business and operations conditions that guide or dictate when various events (like retiring an issuing certificate) take place.